# Ruby: Apply gsub to first and second array items

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have the follow line:

`text.gsub(/,\ /,'| ').first`

But in addition to the first item, I want to apply it to the second item.

How can I do that?

Comment: Your title talks about arrays, but in your code sample you're applying `gsub` to a single string (you're applying it to the whole string btw) and then taking the first line of that string. Could you please clarify?

Comment: @Henrik: If it were, calling `gsub` on it would be an error.

Comment: @sepp2k: that's my point. The title of the question is confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
text.gsub(/,\ /,'| ').take(2)
```